# styling xml-file by including xsl-stylesheet using php

Tags: php, xml, xslt, byte-order-mark

thanks to this helpful community I've been enabled to make a xsl-stylesheet extracting some metainformation from xml-files on my site. Of course, I do not want to code the stylesheet directly in the xml-files, which shall be left untouched. Also, I do not want to preprocess the files in OxyGen and upload the metainfo-files.

So I simply tried this, in metainfo.php:

```
<?php echo '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="metainfo.xsl"?>'; include ('sample.xml') ?>
```

Still, loading metainfo.php will display the whole xml file. The source code looks fine, but when I copy it, save it as xml and open it in OxyGen, there is this little bugger 'ï»¿' in the code, which apperntly is called a BOM:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="metainfo.xsl"?>ï»¿ <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="metainfo.xsl"?>
```

Might this cause the trouble in the browser too? Or is it something else, more basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some extra work, there's what I figured out as a solution myself:

```
<?php
$signatur = $_GET['signatur'];
# LOAD XML FILE
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load( 'xml/'.$signatur.'.xml' );

# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();

# IMPORT STYLESHEET 1
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load( 'metainfo.xsl' );
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );

#PRINT
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
?>
```